# Separating axes from plot area in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I find that data points that lie on or near the axes are difficult to see. The obvious fix, of course, is to simply change the plot area using `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])`, but this is not preferable in all cases; for example, if the x axis is time, then moving the minimum x value to -1 to show activity at 0 does not make sense.

Instead, I was hoping to simply move the x and y axes away from the plot area, like I have done here:
[image: left: Matlab generated, right: desired (image editing software)]
left: MATLAB generated, right: desired (image editing software)

Is there a way to automatically do this in MATLAB? I thought there might be a way to do it by using the `outerposition` axes property (i.e., set it to `[0 0 0.9 0.9]` and drawing new axes where they originally were?), but I didn't get anywhere with that strategy.

Comment: another option could be something like `axis([minx-minx/10 maxx miny maxy])` or some other factor other than 1/10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers here already show you most of the way - here is the last step to separate the x and y axle as per the example you put together.

```
f = figure ( 'color', 'white' );
% create the axes and set some properties
ax = axes ( 'parent', f, 'box', 'off', 'nextplot', 'add', 'XMinorTick', 'on', 'YMinorTick', 'on' );
% plot some data
plot ( ax, 0:10, [0:10].^2, 'rx-' )
% modify the x and y limits to below the data (by a small amount)
ax.XLim(1) = ax.XLim(1)-(ax.XTick(2)-ax.XTick(1))/4;
ax.YLim(1) = ax.YLim(1)-(ax.YTick(2)-ax.YTick(1))/4;
% Set the tick direction
ax.TickDir = 'out';
% draw the plot to generate the undocumented vertex data var
drawnow()

%% R2015a
% X, Y and Z row of the start and end of the individual axle.
ax.XRuler.Axle.VertexData(1,1) = 0;
ax.YRuler.Axle.VertexData(2,1) = 0;


%% R2015b
% extract the x axis vertext data
% X, Y and Z row of the start and end of the individual axle.
vd = get(ax.XAxis.Axle,'VertexData');
% reset the zero value
vd(1,1) = 0;
% Update the vertex data
set(ax.XAxis.Axle,'VertexData',vd);
% repeat for Y (set 2nd row)
vd = get(ax.YAxis.Axle,'VertexData');
vd(2,1) = 0;
set(ax.YAxis.Axle,'VertexData',vd);
```

**Edit:** The vertex is something that Matlab recreates whenever the axes/figure changes size or if you zoom or pan for example.

You can try to counteract this (remember you are using undocumented features here) by adding a listener to attempt to capture this.  We can use the `MarkedClean` event which is called quite a lot of times.

```
addlistener ( ax, 'MarkedClean', @(obj,event)resetVertex(ax) );
```

Where you resetVertex function is something like: (R2015b shown only)

**Edit 2**  added the code to turn off the minor ticks below 0.

```
function resetVertex ( ax )
  % extract the x axis vertext data
  % X, Y and Z row of the start and end of the individual axle.
  ax.XAxis.Axle.VertexData(1,1) = 0;
  % repeat for Y (set 2nd row)
  ax.YAxis.Axle.VertexData(2,1) = 0;

  % You can modify the minor Tick values by modifying the vertex data
  % for them, e.g. remove any minor ticks below 0 
  ax.XAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(:,ax.XAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(1,:)<0) = [];
  ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(:,ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(2,:)<0) = [];
end
```

[image]

Note: this uses undocumented features -> so may only work in certain versions of Matlab (I have added the code for r2015a & r2015b) and Matlab may recreate the vertex data depending on what you do with the plots..

Comment: Very nice! but it doesn't work in 2015a, resulting in error: `No appropriate method, property, or field 'XAxis' for class 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'.`

Comment: I ran your code. It works perfectly. But I see a problem that I don't understand. When I maximize the figure window, the axes get joined again and remain joined even if I restore down the figure window. I'm using MATLAB R2016a. See and zoom this for better explanation of what I am saying http://i.stack.imgur.com/9svbc.jpg  (Your solution is, although, the best of all) :-) ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: @matlabgui First - How do you get to features like that!? Second - I have the same problem as @sardar_Usama, any change to the figure, even just zoom or panning, join back the axis, and running again the line `ax.XRuler.Axle.VertexData...` don't always fix it back

Comment: @EBH and sardar_Usama - see updated edit in the answer - this is a property that Matlab automatically recreates a lot of the time.   and EBH - years of experience teaches you these things! ;)

Comment: Cannot MATLAB be stopped from recreating this or cannot this property be made off for some time? The latest edit solves the problem with small figure window but some ticks appear when the figure window is maximized :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/z4RW1.png

Comment: Your dealing with undocumented features which can and will behave in ways that you may not desire.  I doubt they can be turned off - but you can "work with them"...

Comment: @matlabgui I can't say it's perfect, but it is the closest to optimal +1

Comment: @matlabgui ah exactly what I was hoping to be able to do -- very nice solution!

Comment: @matlabgui for dealing with the y-axis minor ticks you need to adjust the row index you used from the value 1 to the value 2. The value 1 is correct for the x-axis minor ticks but not y-axis i.e. `ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(:,ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(1,:)<0) = []` should read `ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(:,ax.YAxis.MinorTickChild.VertexData(2,:)<0) = []`. Also, instead of `<0` you could define a variable for the min xtick value and min ytick value and use those min values instead of 0.

Comment: @mr.cooper thanks for spotting the typo and suggesting extra control via the min tick values

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way for achieving that:

```
% some data:
x = 1:100;
f=@(x) 5.*x;
y=f(x)+rand(1,length(x))*50;
close all
% plotting:
f1 = figure('Color','white');
ax = axes;
plot(ax,x,y,'o');
% 'clean' the data area a little bit:
box off
ax.TickDir = 'out';
% pushing the axis a bit forward:
lims = axis;
pos = ax.Position;
axis([lims(1)-ax.XTick(2)/5 lims(2)+0.1 lims(3)-ax.YTick(2)/5 lims(4)+0.1])
% Create lines
firstXtick = 0.013; %this value need to be adjusted only once per figure
firstYtick = 0.023; %this value need to be adjusted only once per figure
lx = annotation(f1,'line',[pos(1) pos(1)+firstXtick],...
     [pos(2) pos(2)],'Color',[1 1 1],'LineWidth',1);
ly = annotation(f1,'line',[pos(1) pos(1)],...
     [pos(2) pos(2)+firstYtick],'Color',[1 1 1],'LineWidth',1);
```

Which yields this figure:
[image]

The only thing to adjust here, once per type of figure, is `firstXtick` and `firstYtick` values, that have to be fine tuned to the specific axis. After setting them to the correct value the figure can be resized with no problem. Zoom and pan require a little fixes.

Comment: @achilles & Sardar_Usama I have edited my answer to get a closer result to the figure in the question (in a different way than matlabgui), tell me if it works for you

Comment: this also does the trick -- sorry I can't accept 2 answers ... +1

Comment: @EBH nice hack with `annotation` !   I've already voted it up!

Answer (score 1):

You can start your axes from less than zero and then remove the less than zero ticks from your plot. e.g.

```
plot(0:3:30,0:3:30);     %Some random data for plotting
h = gca;
axis([-1 30 -1 30]);     %Setting the axis from less than zero
box off;                 %Removing box
h.TickDir = 'out';       %Setting Direction of ticks to outwards
h.XTickLabel(1)= {' '};  %Removing the first tick of X-axis
h.YTickLabel(1)= {' '};  %Removing the first tick of Y-axis
```

With this code, you'll get this result:

[image: zeromarkmaynotbeincluded]

This may have a drawback, sometimes, that zero ticks may also get removed (as you can see in above figure). This is because the plot had set the first ticks of axes equal to zero.  This can be avoided using `if` condition. So, the code can be modified as below:

```
plot(0:3:30,0:3:30);
h = gca;
axis([-1 30 -1 30]);
box off;
h.TickDir = 'out';

if str2num(cell2mat(h.XTickLabel(1))) <0
    h.XTickLabel(1)= {' '};
end

if str2num(cell2mat(h.YTickLabel(1))) <0
    h.YTickLabel(1)= {' '};
end
```

The above code will yield the following result:-

[image: zeromarkincluded]

Also note that, for your case, since your axes ticks are very less, `-1` may not be much suitable for the starting value of axes and you may need to use `-0.1` instead i.e. `axis([-0.1 30 -0.1 30]);`

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification of @matlabgui's answer you can track the (major) tick limits:

```
ax = gca();
% Set the tick direction
ax.TickDir = 'out';
% Make sure this stays when saving, zooming, etc
addlistener ( ax, 'MarkedClean', @(obj,event) change_ticks(ax) );
% Draw the plot to generate the undocumented vertex data variable
% and call callback for the first time
drawnow();
```

The callback

```
function change_ticks( ax )       
    % Modify ruler
    ax.XRuler.Axle.VertexData(1,1) = ax.XTick(1);
    ax.XRuler.Axle.VertexData(1,2) = ax.XTick(end);
    ax.YRuler.Axle.VertexData(2,1) = ax.YTick(1);
    ax.YRuler.Axle.VertexData(2,2) = ax.YTick(end);
end
```

I haven't test extensively but seems to work for custom ticks too. This nicely cuts the rulers not only on zero but beyond the fist and last tick. This was tested in Matlab 2019a on Windows and  `ax.XRuler.Axle.VertexData` works just fine. Note this is only for major ticks!